# In a document library, how to determine wether the document is modified or its properties?

Tags: document-library

I need to figure out whether a document is modified in a document library (and not its properties). is it possible to use an event receiver to compute the hash of the document before it is updated and after its updated ? Please share the code along with the references if any.....

Answer (score 1):

You can compare the BeforeProperties and AfterProperties of an event receiver to check for any changes in the properties.

Related question [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/32814/how-to-detect-the-document-has-changed-in-a-document-library-in-sharepoint-2007)

Code would be something like this:

```
    // ItemUpdated
    public override void ItemUpdated(SPItemEventProperties properties)
    {
        base.ItemUpdated(properties);
        if (!EqualProperties(properties.AfterProperties,properties.BeforeProperties))
        { 

        }
    }
```

Where EqualProperties is a method which compares the collections.

If you want to compare hashvalues you can create a text column to store the hash.

```
    public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
    {
        base.ItemAdded(properties);
        this.DisableEventFiring();
        properties.ListItem["myCustomField"] = this.CalculateHash(properties.ListItem.File);
        properties.ListItem.SystemUpdate();
        this.EnableEventFiring();
    }

    public override void ItemUpdated(SPItemEventProperties properties)
    {
        this.DisableEventFiring();
        properties.ListItem["myCustomField"] = this.CalculateHash(properties.ListItem.File);
        properties.ListItem.SystemUpdate();
        this.EnableEventFiring();
        base.ItemUpdated(properties);
        if (properties.ListItem["myCustomField"] != properties.BeforeProperties["myCustomField"])
        { 

        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Anima, but my major concern is to determine whether the document content is modified or not.

Comment: Updated the code. You can use the OpenBinaryStream method on the SPFile object and use the stream to create a hash value with the type System.Security.Cryptography.MD5 which exposes a ComputeHash() method.

Comment: Which reference/namespace is needed to use the CalculateHash() method ? or is it a user-defined method ?

Comment: [More information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.md5(v=vs.90).aspx). The namespace is System.Security.Cryptography.

Answer (score 0):

```
    try
               {
                   this.EventFiringEnabled = false;
                   SPListItem CurrentItem = properties.ListItem;
                   SPFile doc = CurrentItem.File;
                   //Stream stream = doc.OpenBinaryStream(

                   MD5 md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();

                    /* Calculate Hash */
                   byte[] hash1 = md5.ComputeHash(doc.OpenBinary()); //doc.OpenBinary() returns byte[]




                   /* Show Hash in TextBoxes */
                   CurrentItem["CustomFieldName"] = BitConverter.ToString(hash1); 

                   CurrentItem.Update();
               }
               finally
               {
                   this.EventFiringEnabled = true;
               }
```

Need to include the System.Security.Cryptography namespace. Also include the following tag in the elements.xml file before end of Receiver tag :

```
    <Synchronization>Synchronous</Synchronization>
```